react-native-video: requireNativeComponent: "RCTVideo" was not found in the UIManager
I am trying to use react-native-video in my app.
I have this code in my app:
<Video 
source={{uri: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"}}         
/>

I am trying to run the app on both the android emulator and the ios simulator as well as an android device using expo.
Steps npx expo start, press a for android or i for ios, or scan the QR code from the expo app on the android device.
I am getting this error on both the ios and android emulators and the android device too:
requireNativeComponent: "RCTVideo" was not found in the UIManager.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you found a fix yet? I'm facing the same problem

@Community I edited the question and added more info.

@JohnSmith No, not yet.

@JohnSmith You have to run the app in development build, it does not work in expo go.

You have to run the app in development build, it does not work in expo go.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
